# Can context switch take place while in a critical section?

Tags: multithreading

Recently I read an interesting blog comparing mutex and semaphore:
"
http://www.feabhas.com/blog/2009/09/mutex-vs-semaphores-%E2%80%93-part-1-semaphores/
"

Quote from it:
"
If a context switch happens while that task is in the critical region, and another task also calls on P(S), then that second task (and any subsequent tasks) will be blocked from entering the critical region by being put in a waiting state by the operating system. At a later point the first task is rescheduled and calls V(S) to indicate it has left the critical region. The second task will now be allowed access to the critical region.
"

If this is true for semaphore, is it also true for mutex? I don't think it's true as if a block of code is locked, it should be "atomic" that cannot be context switched out or interrupted. Am I right?

Answer (score 15):

No, a context switch can happen almost anywhere. While it's generally a good idea to hold locks for as brief a time as possible, you wouldn't want your entire machine to lock just because one process had as many threads holding locks as there are cores, waiting for something to happen, would you?

The point of a lock is to prevent code which might interfere with the code in the lock from being executed - it's not to stop *all* other code from being executed, in every process in the system. (A context switch to a different process is still a context switch, after all.)

Answer (score 6):

It depends on what version of a "critical section" you're dealing with. Just for example, in OS/2 (the predecessor to current Windows that first included critical sections) entering a critical section prevented switching to a different thread in the same process. In Windows NT, they changed that so thread switching is allowed, so other threads will only be blocked when/if they attempt to enter the same critical section.

In both these cases, a critical section is local to a process so a thread in a different process can never attempt to enter the same critical section.

On other systems, you'll have to look at how a critical section (assuming it has one) is specified to know what it allows/prohibits. Oh, but the name they use varies as well. What Windows calls a critical section is basically just a mutex optimized for use inside a single process. A fair number of systems have something pretty similar, but they do more to emphasize that it's just a fast mutex, so they call it (for one common example) a futex.

They all do roughly similar things, but the details differ between one system and another. There's no universal definition.

Answer (score 0):

A context switch is always possible in Linux, you cannot monopolize the CPU, but threads that fail acquiring the lock will block and thus won't be selected by the scheduler until the lock is available again.

Proof:
Run this code and you will see output from then from g then from f again.

```
 #include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <semaphore.h>

int global=0;
sem_t sem;
void* f(void *a){
    sem_wait(&sem);
    printf("Inside a critical section: %d\n",global++);
    ++global;
    sem_post(&sem);
    return a ;
}

void* g(void *a){
    printf("Function call to g.\n");
    return a ;
}

int main(void){
    pthread_t tids[10];
    sem_init(&sem, 0, 1);
    int i;
    pthread_t new_thread;
    for (i=0; i < 10 ; ++i ){
    if ( i == 8 )
        pthread_create(&new_thread, NULL, g, NULL);
    pthread_create(&tids[i], NULL, f, NULL);
    }
    for (i=0; i < 10 ; ++i ){
    pthread_join(tids[i], NULL);
    }
    pthread_join(new_thread, NULL);
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Most of time, a thread or process can be switch out by scheduler any time, even it is in critical section. Critical section is only a special part of code which should not be shared to executed by other thread. This is not atomic access. Only semaphore or mutex it self is atomic access.
If you want you critical section code execution is atomic, only one thread can run these code even in SMP, you can use spinlock with interrupt disabled. If interrupt is disabled on a processor, scheduler stop working, no isr run. Just your thread run code in critical secion until the thread release spinlock. This is highest code protection which is only used in kernel, because conflict between interrupt and kernel thread only happens in kernel. For example, an isr receive data from device, and a kernel thread read this data.Then spinlock works.